# How can I tell when Blazor has finished rendering a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using server-side Blazor, after selecting from a dropdown I want an input element to appear and get focus. To set the focus I use JSInterop, but the element doesn't get the focus -- I think because it hasn't been rendered yet, because after it's on screen and I choose something else from the dropdown, the input gets the focus correctly.

After changing the boolean that determines whether the input field should show or not, I call StateHasChanged() because that should rerender the DOM if necessary. Then I call SetFocus() which is the JSInterop that simply does an element.focus() javascript call. That part works, as long as the input element is on screen. But it feels like what I want is a StateHasChanged callback, so I can call SetFocus() at that point.

In the HTML code this is the input element that shows/hides and should get the focus:

```
<input style="display: @(displayInputField ?  "block" : "none")" type="text" @ref="searchTermElement" />
```

...and this is the C# code that's supposed to actually make it show/hide and set the focus:

```
displayInputField = (selectedString != "SearchBy" && !showCenterFundList);
this.StateHasChanged();

await SetFocus(elementRef);
```

Maybe the problem isn't what I think (trying to set focus before the element exists), but that's my best guess at this point and where I've been looking for an answer.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to enet for the answer. I ended up with this little chunk of code that solved my problem (and I suspect will veer me away from similar problems in the future):

```
protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
        ...
    else
        if (searchTypeChanged)
        {
            searchTypeChanged = false;
            await SetFocus(searchTermElement);
        }
}
```

Comment: The way you would do this in regular javascript is using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Not sure if that works for Blazor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To set the focus I use JSInterop, but the element doesn't get the
>   focus -- I think because it hasn't been rendered yet

If that is the case, you should use JSInterop from the OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) or OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) methods

Both methods are ideal for using JSInterop...

Hope this helps...

Comment: For anybody else having this problem, enet's answer got me searching in the right direction and I found the following page which helped a lot: [Blazor Lifecycle Methods](https://blazor-tutorial.net/lifecycle-methods).

Comment: "ideal" is a huge exaggeration. it's better than nothing. there is not much ideal in the world